# How can I kill someone else's Python processes on a server without root access?

Tags: python, linux, memory, kill-process

I'm working off-hours today and found that someone is using an unreasonable amount of memory and GPU memory on a shared machine with a process they left running when they left for their holidays. I know they backup their results and the script can be resumed whenever, so I'd like to kill it in order to run my own stuff.

The server is running CentOS version 7.9.2009.

If it matters, the scripts I want to kill are running PyTorch and TensorFlow training scripts that have checkpointing enabled.

An approach I tried involved allocating so much memory that the other processes would get an OOM by just running normally, but it wasn't quite successful.

```
l = []
n = int(1e5)
import time
while n > 0:
    try:
        l.append(' ' * n)
    except:
        n //= 8
        time.sleep(10)
```

It fills up the memory and swap pretty quickly, but won't stay there for long. The issue seems to be that instead of Python raising an exception and triggering the `except` clause, Linux kills the process, showing a single line:

```
Killed
```

I don't know if this is the best approach, but it's something I tried at least.

Comment: On a well-manages system, this should not be possible. The only way I see is if you may write to that users space and (temporarily) consume all of the hard disk quota forcing the process to stop.

Comment: Is the circuit breaker panel locked?

Comment: @stark Unfortunately I'm working from home and don't have telepathic powers.

Answer (score 0):

I the server is properly managed, you cannot:

- no single process should be allowed to eat all the available memory, because there should be limits on what a user is allowed to do
- any decent multi-user system would never allow a non admin user to kill someone's else process

This is the basics in security. But if you think that your fellow is *abusing* system resources and because of that preventing other users to work, you should be able to send a message to the admin team explaining that. **They** can certainly kill the process, but **you** cannot.